# how to check if a user has opened another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets

Hy,
my question is simple:
how to check if a user has opened another spreadsheet?
So I have a master spreadsheet and a slave spreadsheet.
I have some routines that are in the code of the master that run on the slave spreadsheet.
I want to know if there are users that are working on the slave spreadsheet when my routines run from master spreadsheet.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Theres no api to tell if there are users with the spreadsheet open.
However, you can look at the slave's last modified date to tell if someone changed them recently.
You can also have onopen/onedit apps script installed triggers on the slaves and store the date last opened/modified from a browser

Comment: thanks. I have understood that I can use onOpen trigger, but I don't know the commands to store the date last opened/modified; can you give me an help still?

Comment: If you want to store the last opened/modified date from apps script, you can write a library that all (master and slaves) share. You can then store it on the library's scriptDb, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/advanced#calling_a_librarys_database. If you just care about the modified date you can just get it with the spreadsheet feed from your master code, without needing to handle onOpen/onEdit